# Magento catching exceptions and rolling back database transactions

Tags: php, database, magento, transactions, model

I'm working on a Magento module and need to know if it's possible to roll back a series of model saves. Basically, I have five models plus several from my module that I need to save one after the other:

```
admin/role
admin/user
core/website
core/store_group
core/store
mymodule/model1
mymodule/model2
```

My problem is that whenever any of these models throw an exception, I need to go into MySQL and manually delete all the rows that were saved. This is very unproductive.

I'm pretty sure that Magento doesn't have a rollback procedure that I can access in my context. For example, I looked in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and in the save method, the rollback mechanisms are all protected.

So, my question is, is there some best practice for doing database transactions in Magento that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've seen the following used in core code, and it looks like its just what you ordered.

```
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$transactionSave->addObject($model_one)
$transactionSave->addObject($model_two)
$transactionSave->save();
```

The `core/resource_transaction` object allows you to add Magento objects, and perform a mass save on them.  Give that a try, and I'd love to hear how this does, or doesn't, work for you in the comments.

Comment: This worked exactly. Thanks. I also found that I can save the transaction again if I need to add more data to the models. For example, I need to set the website_id and the store_group_id for the store model. After the first transaction save, the model is updated with the primary key. Then I save again and the rows are updated.