# How to save and delete in same transaction

Tags: php, magento, transactions

I need to save some cms pages and delete others in a single transaction.

So, how to I make this:

```
$page1->save();
$page2->delete();
```

A single transaction? For reference, both $page1 and $page2 come from Mage::getModel('cms/page'). Also, I found an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878634/magento-catching-exceptions-and-rolling-back-database-transactions) that tells me how to do two saves in a transaction, but not how to do both a save and delete. How can it be done?

Comment: Note for others: just wanted to make more obvious [the link in the question to Alan Storm's answer regarding `core/resource_transaction`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878634/magento-catching-exceptions-and-rolling-back-database-transactions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you *must* do this in a single transaction, just call `isDeleted(true)` on those items which you wish to be deleted:

```
//Build out previous items, then for each which should be deleted...
$page2->isDeleted(true);

$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$transaction->addObject($page1)
$transaction->addObject($page2)
//$transaction->addObject(...) etc...
$transaction->save();
```

Thought I should add an explanation (from [`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php#L307)):

```
/**
 * Save object data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function save()
{
    /**
     * Direct deleted items to delete method
     */
    if ($this->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete();
    }
    // ...
}
```