# Magento multiple database transactions in single commit

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I know how to do it in zend framework

```
$db->beginTransaction();

try {
   $db->query(...);
   $db->query(...);
   $db->query(...);
   .
   . 
   .
   $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

but I want to do it using magento model, something like

```
$db->beginTransaction();

try {
   $modelOne   = Mage::getModel('modulename/table1');
   $modelTwo   = Mage::getModel('modulename/table2');
   $modelThree = Mage::getModel('modulename/table3');

   $db->query($modelOne);
   $db->query($modelTwo);
   $db->query($modelThree);
   .
   . 
   .
   $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

If anyone of them failed to save then all should be rolled back

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php

This model allow to add another Models as objects in transaction. During save it call `$object->save()` for each added object. If something fails, it call
`$object->getResource()->rollBack()` for each object. You also can add commit callbacks via `addCommitCallback(array($object, 'callbackFunctionName'))`.

If you need delete transaction, call `$transaction->delete()` instead of `$transaction->save()` In this case it call `$object->delete()` instead of `$object->save()` for each object.

Example:

```
try {
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table1'))
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table2'))
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table3'));

    $transaction->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ToxaBse, can you also tell what if I want to save 'modulename/table1' and update 'modulename/table2' and delete 'modulename/table3', how will I achieve that ?

Comment: I didn't use save and delete actions in one transaction, but try to add next line:
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array(Mage::getModel('modulename/table2'), 'delete'));

Answer (score 1):

For INSERT , DELETE and UPDATE in a single transaction (as per your comment) try below,

```
<?php

$id1 = 1; //update id
$id2 = 2; //delete id
$data = array('title'=>'New Title','content'=>'Hello, there..!','status'=>1);
$update = array('title'=>'My title', 'content'=>'Hi, there..!', 'status'=>1); 

try {
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table1')->load($id1)->addData($update));
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table2')->setId($id2)->delete());
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table3')->setData($data));

    $transaction->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I didn't tested this. Just try by your own risk. The problem is you can't get the last insert id for all db-transaction in this. The `delete()` doesn't required to call `save()`. But the INSERT and UPDATE method you need to call the `save()` finally. Please update the result is it working or not.

Comment: This one didn't work for me. There's a similar (but successful) answer from @benmarks to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478840/how-to-save-and-delete-in-same-transaction