# How to optimize saving multiple models?

Tags: magento

I need to manually save a very large number of order items to the database.  I'm currently doing something like this:

```
for($x=0; $x<250000; $x++)
{
    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
    $data = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3);  
    $orderItem->setData($data)->save();
}
```

Attempting to run this code from a shell script takes **forever**.  What strategies can I use to speed up this code?

Comment: Try to look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::_postSaveFieldsUpdate()` and create public method in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item` with similar logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this situation, your best bet to speed this up significantly would be to create custom database queries.

Edit: Related option: try to rewrite the model and resource model to implement a method bulkSave() which is like save() but only creates the corresponding query object and returns it, so it does not actually use the database. Then collect all the queries and run them in big transactions every thousand items or so.

Comment: This approach would certainly be faster, but the complexity of this query is very prohibitive.  If only I was actually setting all items to A,B,C!

Comment: @Toast You could have a different query for each item and put them all into a string which you then execute at the DB after every say 1000 items. Or is it to complex to even compose such a query?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure but take a look @ `Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879133/1191288

You could try doing a batch save on ever X amount

```
 $batch = 500;
 $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
 $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');

 for($x=0; $x<250000; $x++){
     $orderItem->setData( array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3));
     $transactionSave->addObject($orderItem);
     $orderItem->reset()
     if ($x % $batch == 0){
        $transactionSave->save();
        $transactionSave = null;
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
     }
 }

 if($x % $batch > 0)
   $transactionSave->save();
```

Comment: The last comment can't be left uncommented. Loop, right, but in a transaction. So it IS faster.